# How to use Angular and ASP.NET Razor together

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor

How to pass an ASP.NET model's parameter to the `ng-click` method?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addToBasket()"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I want to pass `item.Id` to the `addToBasket` method set by `ng-click` attribute.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addToBasket(@( item.Id ))"></button>
```

Razor's special `@` character is (generally) interpreted regardless of location or surrounding HTML syntax (which is a problem if you ever want to embed a static e-mail address in Razor...)

To escape the `@` (such as for putting an e-mail address) just put it twice:

```
<input type="email" value="foo@@bar.com" />
```

Comment: And why do you have brackets around `item.Id`? I thought that they're not required

Comment: @FrozenHeart Correct, they are not required, but I personally prefer to use parentheses to make it clearer - especially as I'm still a fan of the ASPX `<%= %>` syntax.